# Vue.js | Refused to execute script from 'URL' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Getting this error while browser trying to execute the app.js file of Vue. I tried changing the content-type to javascript, but on checking found that (index.html) file is getting served on the app.js file.

If the page is refreshed, correct app.js file is getting served and the website load without any issue.

Would like to understand why getting the above issue on the first call and after refresh how the correct file is getting served?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, you found any solution?

Comment: @MdRashedulIslam Whether you are using http2 or moved recently to http2?

Comment: It's fixed, I don't know how, but fixed.